# How do I share an existing album?

Tags: icloud, ios, photos.app

I took a bunch of photos on vacation and saved them into an album in the Photos app on iOS 9.  I'd like to now share that album.  Is there a way to do this other than creating a new shared album and manually adding the individual pictures?

I've looked at the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12068?locale=en_US) and they don't describe any way to share an already created album.  The photos are backed up on iCloud, and I can access them via iCloud.com, but there doesn't appear to be a way to even create a new shared album on iCloud.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do have to create a new shared album, but you can create the album from the contents of the existing album so you don't need to find the images again manually.

1. Open the album.
2. Choose Select in the top right, then Select All in the top left.
3. Tap Share in the bottom left, then create a new iCloud Photo Sharing album as usual.

Once you've created the shared album, you can delete the old album.

Comment: The problem is: if the sort order in the album is different from the times the photos were taken, you will loose the album sort.

Comment: Exactly. This doesn’t preserve the sort order which makes it useless.